# Batch file command to scan and kill multiple process if running

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to run a batch file which should kill some specific processes if they are already running.

Below code is for one process like chrome.exe. I want to do this for multiple processes.

```
echo off
tasklist /fi "imagename eq chrome.exe" |find ":" > nul
if errorlevel 1 taskkill /f /im "chrome.exe"
exit
```

Comment: You don't appear to have asked a question or posted none working code requiring a fix! If you want to use a [tag:for-loop] please open a Command Prompt window and enter `for /?` to find out how that command works.

Comment: You've told us what you want (vaguely), but not explained a problem with the code you've posted or asked any sort of question.

Comment: @KenWhite- This code simply not working without giving any error. In .bat file, either command will run or they do not. The description is enough to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give a try with this code to scan what processes are running or not :

```bat
@echo off
Title Scanning and Killing Multi-Processes
Set "Processes=chrome.exe notepad.exe powershell.exe wscript.exe cscript.exe mshta.exe"
for %%a in (%Processes%) Do (
    for /f %%b in ('tasklist /NH /FI "imagename eq %%a"') Do (
        if [%%b]==[%%a] (
            echo %%b is running
            Color 0C
            echo  Killing %%b ...
            Taskkill /f /im "%%b"
        ) else (
            Color 0A
            echo %%a is not running
        )
    )
)
pause & exit
```

Comment: Hi @Hackoo! Why did you put the `2>nul` statement if you know that the process exist ? You will never get an error! So you can remove it ! :)

Comment: Hi  @Sachadee Ok i will remove it :)

Comment: @Hackoo- it worked for me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a list of processes and loop on it with a `FOR` loop.
You don't need to check if they exist, if you gonna kill them!

Just put all processes in the list `$process` and kill them even if they are not running! That's not a problem! 
I putted the `2>nul` to redirect `STDERR` to `NUL`. Like this no error message will be displayed in the shell.

```
@echo off

set "$process=firefox.exe notepad.exe chrome.exe"

for %%a in (%$process%) do taskkill /f /im %%a 2>nul
```

If you really want to waste some processing time and check if the process exist before killing it :

```
@echo off

set "$process=firefox.exe notepad.exe"

for %%a in (%$process%) do tasklist >nul | find "%%a" && taskkill /f /im %%a
```

Comment: In your second code example, I would suggest moving the `>nul` before the conditional ampersands.

Comment: Note for the OP : like @Compo said I putted the `>nul` statement for the `find` operation that's more logical!! If you don't want any output at all you can also put it again at the end of the `taskkill` operation.